# How to get the difference between two Immutable.js Map?

Tags: javascript, immutable.js

I have two immutable map:

```
const first_map = Map({a: 1, b: 2)}
const second_map = Map({a: 1, b: 3)}
```

How to get the difference?
I should get:

```
Map({b: 3})
```

Comment: did these maps have the same keys ??

Comment: yes, because i need to get the updated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible approach is using **Map.filter()** - which is actually [**Collection.Keyed.filter()**](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Collection.Keyed/filter) - on the second map with one condition: for a given element of this Map, there should be no element in another Map with the same key. For example:

```js
const Map = Immutable.Map;

const first_map = Map({a: 1, b: 2, c: 4});
const second_map = Map({a: 1, b: 3, d: 5});

const diff = second_map.filter((v, k) => first_map.get(k) !== v);

console.log(diff.toString()); // Map { "b": 3, "d": 5 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/immutable/3.8.2/immutable.min.js"></script>
```

Strictly speaking, one should check for `has` first - as `Map.get(key)` returns undefined if there's no such key, but there might be valid cases for Map containing `undefined`. Still, I'd encourage using `null` for such values.